# Automapper 5.0 throwing an exception

Tags: c#, automapper

Exception:

> Configuration = 'AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Code:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<CrmMapper.ExamModel, CrmMapper.ExamInventoryModel>()
           .ForMember(v => v.ExamId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ExamId));              
        });

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var source = new ExamModel();            
var dest = mapper.Map<ExamModel, ExamInventoryModel> (source);
```

Comment: Please include the definitions for `CrmMapper.ExamModel` and `CrmMapper.ExamInventoryModel`.  Without know the details of what you're mapping, it's almost impossible to tell what could be the cause.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.I will delete this question.